# Is there a way to integrate PureScript and Vite together?

Tags: vite, purescript

I use `spago` to build `src/Main.purs` to `output/Main/index.js`.
I am trying to use Vite for the bundling tool and have successfully loaded `output/Main/index.js` in `src/main.ts`.
Vite can import image files, but I am having trouble using this from PureScript.

The approach I have tried is to first import the image file using regular JavaScript and then make it referenceable from the purs file using PureScript's FFI.
However, this approach did not work with the following error message:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./typescript.svg" from "output/Constants/foreign.js". Does the file exist?
```

Is there any good solution?

---

```
/
├ public/
│ └ vite.svg
├ output/
├ src/
│ ├ Constant.js
│ ├ Constant.purs
│ ├ Main.purs
│ ├ main.ts
│ ├ style.css
│ ├ typescript.svg
│ └ vite-env.d.ts
├ index.html
├ package.json
├ spago.yaml
└ tsconfig.json
```

---

`src/main.ts`:

```
import './style.css'

import { main } from "../output/Main";

main();
```

---

`src/Constants.purs`:

```
module Constants
  ( typescriptlogo
  , vitelogo
  ) where

foreign import typescriptlogo :: String
foreign import vitelogo :: String
```

---

`src/Constants.js`:

```js
import typescriptlogo from './typescript.svg'
import vitelogo from '/vite.svg'

export { typescriptlogo, vitelogo }
```

---

`src/Main.purs`:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Constants (vitelogo)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Halogen (liftEffect)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.Aff as HA
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Halogen.HTML.Properties as HP
import Halogen.VDom.Driver (runUI)

type State = Unit

component :: forall query input output m. H.Component query input output m
component =
  H.mkComponent
    { initialState
    , render
    , eval
    }
  where
  initialState :: input -> State
  initialState _ = unit

  render :: forall w i. State -> HH.HTML w i
  render _ =
    HH.div []
      [ HH.a
          [ HP.href "https://vitejs.dev"
          ]
          [ HH.img [ HP.src vitelogo ] ]
      ]

  eval = H.mkEval H.defaultEval

main :: Effect Unit
main = HA.runHalogenAff do
  body <- HA.awaitBody
  _io <- runUI component unit body

  liftEffect $ log $ "Application Start"
```